# Do these matrices have common eigenvalues?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I am struggling with this problem. $D$ is a diagonal matrix with distinct entries and $z$ has no zero entries and $\rho\ne 0$ is some scalar.

$$(D+\rho zz^\top)x=\lambda x$$

What is $z^\top x$ and do $D$ and $D+\rho z z^\top$ have common eigenvalues?

When I simplify I get $d_i x_i+\rho (z^\top x) z_i=\lambda x_i$ and $z^\top x=\frac{(\lambda-d_i)x_i}{\rho z_i},\ \forall i$.

How do I prove the second statement? Is there anything more to this?

Comment: The intuition is that they do not have common eigenvalues. At least, we can find examples to demonstrate. for example, D=[1 0; 0 2] and rho=1, and z=[1 1]^T.

Comment: The second claim is immediate from the min-max principle.